# Контроллер DefaultController не может найти представление "index". Yii

Tags: yii

Создал через gii новый модуль, пробую перейти в него и вот такая ошибка вылетает
Контроллер DefaultController не может найти представление "index".
код контроллера

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{ public function actionIndex() {  $this->render('index');  } }
```

Comment: значит, представления не существует

Comment: нет лежит в папке   /protected/modules/mymodule/views/index.php

Answer (score 1):

а контроллер правильно создали?

в Model Class *

указываем нашу модель явно

application.modules.admin.models.Page

в

Controller ID

дописываем имя модуля admin/page

вот подробная [инструкция](http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/03/yii_31.html)